# DataContractSerializer with MemoryStream missing bytes

Tags: c#, wcf, stream

I am trying to use the WCF DataContractSerializer to serialize a DataContract object into a memoryStream.

Then I use the memoryStream.ToArray to get the serialized content.

Finally, I persist the memoryStream into a file using anther fileStream.

My initial implement is like this. I am missing bytes at the end of the persisted File.

```
    public virtual string SerializeTransient(DataObject data, string targetPath)
    {
        string securityCode;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, new XmlWriterSettings {Indent = true}))
            {
                _serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, data);

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    securityCode = CalculateSecurityCode(memoryStream.ToArray());
                    memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }

        return securityCode;
    }
```

If I move the persist logic out of the inner using{} block (see below), the output is correct. It almost feels like the WriteObject function didnt finish what it is doing. Could someone please explain to me what is happening there? Thanks.

```
    public virtual string SerializeTransient(DataObject data, string targetPath)
    {
        string securityCode;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, new XmlWriterSettings {Indent = true}))
            {
                _serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, data);
            }

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                securityCode = CalculateSecurityCode(memoryStream.ToArray());
                memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
            }
        }

        return securityCode;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XmlWriter has an internal buffer. You should either Close/Dispose XmlWriter or call the [XmlWriter.Flush()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to force all content to be written to underlying stream (memoryStream).

If memoryStream.ToArray() is called before writer.Flush() then some bytes will possibly remain in internal writer buffer.

Comment: I see. That is why calling Dispose() on the XMLWriter made a difference. Thanks for the reply. So when you write to a XMLWriter, you are actually writing to its internal buffer? The internal buffer is then flashed out to the underlying stream when Close() or Dispose() or Flush() is called explicitly?

Comment: yes, actual write chain is XmlWriter -> XmlWriter internal StreamWriter -> MemoryStream. internal StreamWriter has a char[1024] buffer, so content is written to memory stream as char[1024] chunks. If your content has 1030 characters length, then last 6 chars will stay in buffer until you will call Flush or Close/Dispose the writer.